# python os.path.exists not working

Tags: python

I apologize ahead of time as I am very new to python and I wrote what I thought was a very simple script to find missing directories. The script reads in from a file one line at a time (each line contains a unix style directory), it then checks to see if that directory exists and if it does not exist then it displays a message and it writes that directory to an outputfile.

The problem is that I have directories in the output file that exist and I am not sure as to why that is...

I know for certain that the first directory listed in the output file exists as I have checked the first dozen or so from the beginning of the file. I consistently see that the first directory does exist but the rest that I have checked do not.  I have even ran the same check in the python interactive mode and it returns True so I do not understand why this directory is written to the output file.

any ideas?

```
import os
f = open('missingdirs.out', 'w')
for line in file('alldirs.txt', 'r'):
     if not os.path.exists(line.strip()):
          print "Could not find the path specified: " + line.strip()
          f.write(line.strip()+'\n')
f.close()
```

Sample of the input file below (These are absolute paths):

```
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_Can
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_Do
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_How
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_Is-Are
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_What
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_When
/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_Where
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input file as well?

Comment: Sounds like `alldirs.txt` doesn't work the way you think it does

Comment: Furthermore - when you use .strip() you only remove whitespace - make sure that you do not have \n, \r or something similar in your strings as well when you check if the dirs exist.

Comment: Does alldirs.txt contain relative or absolute filenames? If relative, you will want to `os.path.join()` them with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added a sample of the input file above. These directories are absolute paths.

Comment: is that supposed to be `for line in open('alldirs.txt','r'):`?

Answer (score 0):

Some simple troubleshooting steps....

```
with open('alldirs.txt','r') as in_:
    lines = list(map(str.strip,in_.readlines()))
print('\n'.join(lines[:10]))
# maybe your input is not what you think it is

import os
path = r"/home/sites/shared/lingui/course/0418-0001_AUT_Can"
print(os.path.exists(path))
# use a string literal rather than the file read -- does THAT work?
```

I can all but guarantee that the issue is with your input file being improperly formatted.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this and get back to you. I'm just bogged down with some other work at the moment.